# Angular2 Cannot find reference to file

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the ng2-map library which requires the @types/googlemaps to be defined.
I did add a reference to the googlemaps' index.d.ts

in my `browser.d.ts`

```
///<reference path="./googlemaps/index.d.ts"/>
```

Despite this, I am having many typescript errors saying :

```
TS2688 Cannot find type definition file for 'googlemaps'
/// <reference types="googlemaps"
```

Where should I define the googlemaps type so that my library would know about it ? Apparently putting it in my main `browser.d.ts` isn't enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I face the same problem. You can solve it by upgrading to new version. Now `ng2-map` has been renamed as `@ngui/map`, as you can see in [changelog](https://github.com/ng2-ui/map/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

> ### 0.17.0 (2017-03-29)
>
> renamed module to @ngui/map

Please read the page below to see instructions:

[@ngui/map](https://github.com/ng2-ui/map)

Comment: How comes, I am still getting this error after upgraded to the latest v.1.18.8 with $ npm install @ngui/map @types/googlemaps --save. Do I have to import type definitions some how?